# Change class for dropdown menu as per region in Drupal

Tags: 7, theming

I used `hook_menu_link` for adding class for the drop down using semantic UI frame work. It will added class to all menu.
My code is:

```
function semanticUI_menu_link(array $variables) {
  //print'<pre>';print_r($variables);die();
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';
 $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'item';
  if ($element['#below']) {
    // Prevent dropdown functions from being added to management menu so it
    // does not affect the navbar module.
    if (($element['#original_link']['menu_name'] == 'management') && (module_exists('navbar'))) {
      $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
    }
    elseif ((!empty($element['#original_link']['depth'])) && ($element['#original_link']['depth'] == 1)) {
      // Add our own wrapper.
      unset($element['#below']['#theme_wrappers']);
      $sub_menu = '<ul class="menu">' . drupal_render($element['#below']) . '</ul>';
      // Generate as standard dropdown.
      $element['#title'] .= ' <i class="dropdown icon basic"></i>';
      $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'ui dropdown';
      $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;

      // Set dropdown trigger element to # to prevent inadvertant page loading
      // when a submenu link is clicked.
      //$element['#localized_options']['attributes']['data-target'] = '#';
      //$element['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'dropdown-toggle';
      //$element['#localized_options']['attributes']['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
    }
    elseif ((!empty($element['#original_link']['depth'])) && ($element['#original_link']['depth'] == 2)) {
      // Add our own wrapper.
      unset($element['#below']['#theme_wrappers']);
      $sub_menu = '<ul class="menu">' . drupal_render($element['#below']) . '</ul>';
      // Generate as standard dropdown.
      $element['#title'] .= ' <i class="dropdown icon"></i>';
      $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'dropdown-bottom';
      $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;

      // Set dropdown trigger element to # to prevent inadvertant page loading
      // when a submenu link is clicked.
      //$element['#localized_options']['attributes']['data-target'] = '#';
      //$element['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'dropdown-toggle';
      //$element['#localized_options']['attributes']['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
    }
  }
  // On primary navigation menu, class 'active' is not set on active menu item.
  // @see https://drupal.org/node/1896674
  if (($element['#href'] == $_GET['q'] || ($element['#href'] == '<front>' && drupal_is_front_page())) && (empty($element['#localized_options']['language']))) {
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'active';
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

Is there any way to add class for specific region menu. If menu is in sidebar so is this possible to add different class for menu. Currently its working fine its drop down menu but i want for side bar it will show simple menu.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to achieve, it is possible with plain CSS?

Comment: i am making theme using semantic-ui frame work. So i don't want to use css. I just want to use semantic-ui elements for this.